# Is it possible to expose/add your custom APIs to the existing Spark's driver REST endpoints?

Tags: java, rest, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.1.1

Spark exposes certain API endpoints (usually mounted at /api/v1). Is their someway to expose custom end-points using the same spark server?

( Using Spark 2.1.1 , Structured Streaming )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible to achieve this with proxy http server (apache http server or something else). It can forward requests to your api/server or to apache spark based on context path (such as /api/v1 or something else), see for example [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)